# Add CMS static-block in attribute text area?

Tags: attributes, static-block

I have some share-buttons in a static-block. I control some content on product-level by custom attributes. Is it possible to add a static block in a attribute text area. I tried with `{{block type="cms/block" block_id="your_block_id"}}` but it's not working?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

On [this](http://belmondo-dev01.e-sites.nl/familieboek.html) page, look for the text "Famke (en Joost) – Deventer". This content is added at Manage product > product in an Attribute text-area. Below this alinea (in the same text-area i want to add the static-block (with its content, the share buttons). I have to do it like this because of some CSS classes.

Comment: it's maybe just me, but could you be more specific as to what you tend to achieve?

Comment: i updated my question...

Answer (score 2):

I've had also the same issue and I found little free extension here http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/static-blocks-everywhere.html

which allows you to add static block in Description (short too), Agreement and Category description.

If you will take a look at code of this extension you will have clear picture of how to implement it to the custom attributes on product page.

I will update this answer once I will test it with the other combinations.

**UPD:**
That Extension that I mentioned earlier does what it says, but for only three instances, Agreement, Category and Product Descriptions (You can see that in code)

Also you can read here 
http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/product-text-area-attribute-with-wysiwyg-src-quot-123-123-media-url-quot-folder-imagejpg-quot-125-125-not-parsed-41450.html

How to parse static block in any text area attribute.

Now I'm able to display my responsive tabs with very flexible way to update and create content - calling specific static blocks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible out of the box, but with some coding is possible.
First of all you need to have that attribute as a textarea with WYSIWYG support and allow html on frontend. You can set these values from `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes`.
Then you need to allow media directives in product attributes.
You can do that from `System->Configuration->Catalog->Frontend`. Set the value for `Allow Dynamic Media URLs in Products and Categories` to `Yes`.

Now you need to change the template processor for the catalog attributes.
By default the textarea attribute values are parsed by the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Template_Filter`.
This is defined in the `config.xml` file of the catalog module.

```
<config>
    ....
    <global>
        ...
            <catalog>
                ...
                <content>
                    <tempate_filter>catalog/template_filter</tempate_filter><!-- this defines the template processor-->
                </content>
                ...
            </catalog>
        ...
    </global>
    ...
</config>
```

You have 2 options here.
**Option 1.**
Rewrite the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Template_Filter` and add a new method called `blockDirective` that you can copy from `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter`.
You can choose this method if you want more control or if you want to add extra modifications to the `{{}}` directive parsing.
But I wouldn't use that. I would go with ...

**Option 2.**.
Change the template processor. Make the catalog use the same processor that is used for cms blocks and pages because they already have support for `{{block}}` directives.
An even better idea would be to use the template processor for widgets. This will allow you to use `{{widget}}` directives in addition to `{{block}}` directives.
To do that, just create a new module. Let's call it `Easylife_Directive`.
You can even use one of the modules you have if you don't want to create a new one just for this.
If you create a new module you will need this file.  (If you use an existing module you can skip it).

`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Directive.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Directive>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog /><!-- Should be loaded after the catalog module -->
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Directive>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Directive/etc/config.xml` - the config file where you change the template processor.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Directive>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Easylife_Directive>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <catalog>
            <content>
                <tempate_filter>widget/template_filter</tempate_filter><!-- change the template filter -->
            </content>
        </catalog>
    </global>
</config>
```

If you want to use one of your existing modules just copy this inside the `<global>` tag of the `config.xml` file of the module.

```
<catalog>
    <content>
        <tempate_filter>widget/template_filter</tempate_filter><!-- change the template filter -->
    </content>
</catalog>
```

Comment: sorry so just for **option 2** what are exactly the steps i have to follow. Just for the `{{block}}` option. Its not totally clear where i have to start. I configured the things by Magento admin... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Meez For test purposes, create the 2 files I mentioned and clear the cache.

Comment: and why you call it Easylife_Directive. Is it just a name..?

Comment: **Step 1)** I created `app/etc/modules/Easylife_Directive.xml` **Step 2)** What do i have to do next? Which second file i have to create? Thanks

Comment: app/code/local/Easylife/Directive/etc/config.xml and yes...the `Easylife_Directive` is just the module name. You can change it to whatever you want, but make sure you change it everywhere. Even in the file names.

Comment: ok i created the 2 files. But still i see `{{block type="cms/block" block_id="share_buttons_product_page"}}` on the [frontend](http://belmondo-dev01.e-sites.nl/familieboek.html). Did i forget anything? Thanks

Comment: Did you clear the cache? Didyou also follow the suggestions at the top of the answer.

Comment: Yes i cleared cache. But the 2 suggestions: If you put `Enable WYSIWYG` on 'YES' you can't choose `Allow HTML Tags on Frontend` ? What do i have to do to get it working you think?

Comment: do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I think it will be set by dwfault to true whrn you enable the editor.

Comment: Ok i enabled the editor but the cms-block is still not loading in the attribute text-area? Thanks again!

Comment: Do you have any clue what to do? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to parse any WYSIWYG editor

> Mage::helper('cms')->getPageTemplateProcessor()->filter($this->getContent());

you need to replace `$this->getContent()` with your attribute's content like `Mage::registry('current_product')->getSomeAttributeByCode()`

It will work for your requirement!